# res.redirect after res.json in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code below
I want to redirect and return the response as well, can someone help me in this?
What is the better solution for this?

```
try {
  res.json(await example.preview(access_token, context, id, body))
  res.redirect(`${sso.host}/session/login?grant_type=bearer&access_token=${access_token}&remember_me=true&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
 'https://example.com'
 )}`);
} catch (e) {
  logger.info(e);
  next(e);
}
```

Comment: Your situation is not making sense. `res.json` is used to return a json in the HTTP response, `res.redirect` is to respond a 302 HTTP Response which **has no data** and will redirect the client. **You can not redirect a request and returning some data as well.**

Comment: I cannot handle it in client side as i have token in the redirect_url what is the better way to do this?

Comment: what is your purpose ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `res.json` to return a regular 200 response, with any data you wish and also add a `redirectURL` item, which will be handled on the client side.

Example on client side:

```
// Simulate a mouse click:
window.location.href = redirectURL;

// Simulate an HTTP redirect:
window.location.replace(redirectURL);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

It isn't possible (and simply doesn't make sense) to simultaneously say both:

- Here is the thing you asked for
- The thing you asked for is not here, you need to request this URL instead

(This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); you might want to ask a new question about the problem you are trying to solve by asking how to do this impossible thing).